# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd'

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

When loading my app spring context, I am getting the following error (**only on Linux machine, on Windows seem to work somehow**):

> Failed to read schema document
>   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd',
>   because 
>   1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema.

Stacktrace follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/score/context/scoreRepositoryContext.xml]
2015-03-30 11:07:49:336 127901 [main] WARN org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 150; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:433)
at 
...
at org.springframework.shell.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:58)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
```

Any idea why is that?

Comment: It seems like you have a connection issue in your Linux machine, make sure you could access http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd Maybe a firewall/proxy is in there?

Comment: seem to work.. just did a :wget http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd                     and it downloaded the XSD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly a Spring library version issue.

[**Update your Spring libraries** on the Linux machine](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/115539-failed-to-read-http-www-springframework-org-schema-context-spring-context-3-0-xsd):

> Make sure that there aren't any conflicting jars (different spring
>   versions) on the classpath. If you use spring 3.0 there should be no
>   big fat spring.jar (which is spring 2.5 and before). Next if you are
>   creating a uber jar which contains all packages als make sure you copy
>   xsd files also.

[**Credit**: [Marten Deinum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/115539-failed-to-read-http-www-springframework-org-schema-context-spring-context-3-0-xsd?p=585141#post585141) (as above), and Tristan and Michael Lee improved this answer by removing network connectivity check suggestion.]

Comment: just did a :wget springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd and it downloaded the XSD ...

Comment: So it's not a connectivity issue.  Look next to the library differences between the machines.

Comment: You're right , i happens that i had diff versions of spring jar's!

Comment: At runtime, Spring is supposed to find the xsd in spring packaged jars, not on the internet. The correspondance between the URL and the real location inside each spring jar can be found in META-INF/spring.schemas. I've modified the answer accordingly

Comment: Well, my concern was to remove everything about connectivity/web/internet, which is misleading.

Comment: @Tristan:  I looked at this more closely after receiving another suggestion like yours and I see what you mean.  I've restored your edit.  Michael Lee: I've accepted your edit but rolled back to Tristan's since he'd said the same thing earlier.  Thanks to both of you.