# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven' 'context:component-scan'

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

Can anyone identify what is wrong with the namespace declaration below? I've mentioned all the namespaces and gave references to the schema files. Not sure what else is missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="    
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd    
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd    
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Error message:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
>     - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd', because 1)
>   could not find the document; 2) the    document could not be read; 3)
>   the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

Comment: sounds like an eclipse issue

Comment: This would happen if you cannot access the mentioned [spring-tx.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd).  Test your access by bringing it up in a web browser.  I can access that XSD, and your XML does validate successfully for me.

Comment: If that's not it, note also that there have been [cases where conflicting versions of Spring jars have resulted in errors resembling XSD access errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29472455/290085).

Comment: @kjhughes.. thanks. I tried your suggestion but it didn't help. I'm able to access the XSDs also. I finally gave up and just turned off XML validation.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer STS over Eclipse and this is how one can reproduce the problem...

I have a Maven project with a Spring context dependency:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests.so.q34779551</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SO-q34779551</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I now create `spring.xml` in `src/main/resources` same as yours I have same problems:

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The problem is, that `spring-tx` and `spring-context` is not in dependencies - when added, error is fixed.

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34789439/384674).

Comment: but I do have the tx and context jars in my project dependency. Application works fine when deployed to websphere on RAD. It is just RAD (Eclipse) complaining..

Comment: It might be a lot of things in Eclipse, proxy for example... You can als check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1075043/384674) for a local schema versions...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I created Spring MVC project using Maven which automatically adds core dependencies but sometime build doesn't get successful, in that case if you will enable Annotated component scan it will give the above error.

Solution : Just update Spring Core Dependencies in Pom.xml by adding
below tag according to  your Spring version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
```